# Can I develop Scripts for DJI Drones and in which programming language?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am thinking about buying a DJI Mavic pro Drone to develop my own scripts for Deep learning tests like autonomous flights, object recognition, and a lot more.

I want to know which libraries or SDK are out there to do this and what kind of programming languages it requires to do so?

I know some cheap drones allow you to program scripts in Python or many different languages and also you can change prewritten functions of their SDK, but what about DJI?

Answer (score 1):

All SDKs and documentation are available here: http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/

For Mavic Pro, we support iOS and Android and we have for both an SDK with all controls you might want along with a VideoPreviewer for handling the video feed and a UILibrary for drone-specific app UI objects.

**For languages:**

iOS: Objective-C, Swift or C++ will work fine. 
Android: Java.

Finally if you are interested in object recognition, check out this project:
https://github.com/game-of-drones/dji-mobilesdk-vision

Answer (score 0):

For a Mavic I think it would have to be iOS or Android
http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/